# Check if a json object contains a specific string with php

Tags: php, json, api

I am using an API from battle.net which uses an object called 'type'. I need to check what the type is, so I can display an appropiate word to match the type. ie. If the type is 'itemLoot' display 'has looted' or if the type is 'playerAchievment' display 'has achieved'.

The PHP script is as followed:

```
foreach($feed->news as $newsfeed) {
                if ($feedcount >= 12) {
                    break;
                }
                    echo $newsfeed->character . PHP_EOL;
                        $type = $newsfeed->type . PHP_EOL;
                        $iteminfo = $newsfeed->itemId . PHP_EOL;
                        $itemnumber = $newsfeed->itemId;
                        if ($type="itemPurchase"){
                            echo " has looted";
                             $itemurl = file_get_contents("https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/item/$itemnumber?locale=en_GB&apikey=f43uf742srjkmvpnk76u52pw5nz5kga5");
                            $itemname = json_decode($itemurl);
                            echo " " . $itemname->name . "<br>";
                        }
                        elseif ($type="itemPurchase"){
                            echo " has purchased";
                        }
                elseif ($type="playerAchievement"){
                    echo " has Achieved<br>";
                }

                    ++$feedcount;

            }
```

The JSON file I am working with is:

```
{
"lastModified": 1484511989000,
"name": "Renascence",
"realm": "Vek'nilash",
"battlegroup": "Glutsturm / Emberstorm",
"level": 25,
"side": 1,
"achievementPoints": 2565,
"emblem": {
    "icon": 60,
    "iconColor": "ffb1b8b1",
    "iconColorId": 14,
    "border": 3,
    "borderColor": "ffffffff",
    "borderColorId": 14,
    "backgroundColor": "ff4f2300",
    "backgroundColorId": 44
},
"news": [{
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Õpiate",
    "timestamp": 1484514300000,
    "itemId": 139074,
    "context": "world-quest-7",
    "bonusLists": [3432, 1502, 3336]
}, {
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Massaicus",
    "timestamp": 1484514240000,
    "itemId": 124299,
    "context": "raid-mythic",
    "bonusLists": [1799, 1507, 3441]
}, {
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Druzzen",
    "timestamp": 1484514060000,
    "itemId": 141257,
    "context": "world-quest-9",
    "bonusLists": [3474, 1507, 1674]
}, {
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Massaicus",
    "timestamp": 1484514000000,
    "itemId": 124187,
    "context": "raid-mythic",
    "bonusLists": [1799, 1522, 3442]
}, {
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Snippin",
    "timestamp": 1484513820000,
    "itemId": 134316,
    "context": "world-quest-9",
    "bonusLists": [3474, 1517, 3336]
}, {
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Snippin",
    "timestamp": 1484513580000,
    "itemId": 143684,
    "context": "world-quest-9",
    "bonusLists": [3474, 1512, 3336]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic Error ;)

```
if ($type == "itemPurchase"){
...
}
```

and not

```
if ($type = "itemPurchase"){
...
}
```

...
And do not forget, the fist if and second are the same, maybe you should switch the string to the right thing ;)